# How to localize the text of a program based on a setting?

Tags: java, localization

I have a `Language` class, for example, which will contain constant attributes of type `String`, which will be used all over the program to print `x` or `y` `Strings` based on a setting when launching the program.

How could I do this? I throught of using `Enum`, but I lack experience with them and failed to apply them correctly; tried diferent classes which inherit `Language` and must specify the values of each `String`, but that looked like a home-made `Enum`.

As a plus, I'd love to have an XML file containing each `String` content, but I have absolutely no idea of grabbing values of an XML file in java (I probably know how to do them separatedly). If possible, a little example or documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html

Comment: Seems I didn't search as hard as I could. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties files, i.e. naming them en-GB.properties, en-US.properties etc, this is how the file looks like:

en-GB.properties

```
file=File
edit=Edit
```

it-IT.properties

```
file=File
edit=Modifica
```

The string before the '=' symbol is the property name, the string after it is the property value, this is the code to access it:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
        //load a properties file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("it-IT.properties"));

        //get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("file"));  //prints "File"
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("edit"));//prints "Modifica"

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps